# equivalent of this in STL

Tags: c++, stl

Give the following code

```
inline void inlineConvertPackFilename(char *name)
{
    while(*name)
    {
        if(*name == '\\')
        {
            *name = '/';
        }
        else
        {
            *name = (int) tolower(*name);
        }

        name++;
    }
}
```

Question is simple, is exist intro `STL` any equivalnet of this function ?

Usage is :

```
static char filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
inlineConvertPackFilename(filename);
```

Yes i know that is an `C` code but i want the equivalent in c++.

Comment: [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Comment: Why would there be an algorithm for doing something so specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `std::for_each()` because you asked for STL:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void inlineConvertPackFilename(std::string& name)
{
    std::for_each(name.begin(), name.end(), [](auto& c) {
        if (c == '\\')
        {
            c = '/';
        }
        else
        {
            c = tolower(c);
        }
    });
}


int main()
{
    static std::string filename("C:\\FOO\\bar\\Baz.txt");
    inlineConvertPackFilename(filename);
    return 0;
}
```

But that's really unnecessary as you can use a range `for` instead:

```
void inlineConvertPackFilename(std::string& name)
{
    for (auto& c : name)
    {
        if (c == '\\')
        {
            c = '/';
        }
        else
        {
            c = tolower(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
inline std::string inlineConvertPackFilename(std::string name)
{
    std::transform( name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), []( char c ) {
        if( c == '\\' ) return '/';
        return tolower(c);
    } );
    return name;
}
```

usage:

```
auto filename = inlineConvertPackFilename( tmpFilename );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

void convert(std::string &name)
{
  std::replace(name.begin(), name.end(), '\\', '/');

  std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);
}
```

The trouble is that std::replace() only works for 1:1 replacements (e.g. replace one character by another character). It's OK for your use, but if you need to do a more general multi-character substring replacement, you'd have to roll your own with string::find() and string::replace().

Comment: Another (minor) drawback is that this approach makes two passes through the input string, while the original code made only one. So it's slightly slower.